# Java: How to implement subsets of a subset?

Tags: java, algorithm, set, subset

Following implementation finds subsets of a set, but could anyone please explain what `if((i&(1<<j)) > 0)` is doing and for what reason?

The comment don't seem to help out and tried console logging, yet it is still difficult to see what it is doing exactly.

```
//Print all subsets of given set[]
static void printSubsets(char set[]) {
    int n = set.length;

    //Run a loop for printing all 2^n subsets one by one
    for(int i=0; i<(1<<n); i++) {
        System.out.print("{ ");

        //Print current subset 
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {

            //(1<<j) is a number with jth bit 1
            //so when we 'and' them with the 
            //subset number we get which numbers
            //are present in the subset and which are not
            if((i&(1<<j)) > 0) {
                System.out.print(set[j] + " ");
            }
        }
            System.out.println("}");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    char set[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    printSubsets(set);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "subset of a subset"? This prints all subsets of the given set (at least for small sets, at one point you run out of bits in an `int`).

Comment: @Thilo Sorry that was a typo, meant subset of set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a subset, each element may be either present, or not. So each element has only 2 possible states: in or out. 1 or 0. If we look at the binary representation of numbers from 0 to `2^n -1`, where `n` is the number of elements, for example when `n=3`, we have:

```
    cba
0 = 000
1 = 001
2 = 010
3 = 011
4 = 100
5 = 101
6 = 110
7 = 111
```

There are 8 possible subsets, and the bits represent whether an element is in the subset or not.
This is the idea used by the program:

- The outer loop goes from `0` until `2^n-1`.
- The inner loop goes from `0` until `n-1`.
- `1<<j` is 1 shifted to the left `j` times.

For example, when `i=3`, that corresponds to bits `011`.
We loop from `0` until `2`, comparing `i` against `001`, `010`, and `100`.
For these values, the expression `i & (1 << j)` will be evaluated as
`011 & 001 = 001`, `011 & 010 = 010`, and `011 & 100 = 000`, respectively.
The first two are greater than 0, the last one is not.
So `System.out.print(set[j] + " ")` will print `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!